# Big problem with types: index.d.ts is not a module

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, soundmanager2, react-typescript

I install @types/soundmanager2@2.97.3 and i have the latest version of the typescript.
My code

```js
import { soundManager } from 'soundmanager2'
```

I get this error

```js
File '/home/i/app/node_modules/@types/soundmanager2/index.d.ts' is not a module.  TS2306
```

The fact is that there is no solution to this problem anywhere, help who understands what the problem is

Comment: Did you install soundmanager2 as well or just the typings